# Working with xcappdata files in unit tests

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing

I have created a unit test target to test migration of existing app data into to my new app verison. To do this, I have saved a `.xcappdata` bundle from a real device containing some typical real-world data, and I now want to base my unit test target on this data.

I added the file to Xcode (but not to any target), and changed the "Test application data" for that migration unit test target to point to this bundle.

However, when I run the unit tests, I get the following error dialog:

> Application data package not copied to the Simulator
>
> It appears you are running 'MyApp.app' on the iPhone 5s Simulator for the first time, and therefore do not yet have a data folder created.  The application data package will be installed the next time you run your app in the Simulator.

(And the sandbox directory does not contain the contents of the .xcappdata bundle).

I simply do not understand this error message or how to fix it. I do not want the app data in my main app target (which is how I interpret the suggestion in the error dialog), since the data is for one unit test suite only. By looking at the "Edit scheme..." dialog I get the impression that I can use different data sets for each test target, which is exactly what I intend to do. Did I misunderstand how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see this in Xcode 5, but I do with the Xcode 6 beta.  Any chance that's what you're using?

Comment: I don't have this problem anymore, so I assume it could have been an Xcode bug.